# Retrieve data of a text field in another HTML page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to copy the value of a text field in **form.html** to **main.html**. First, **main.html** will be launched. Then, **form.html** will be displayed after clicking the 'Add' button, the user will enter a value, click 'Submit' and the control should be transferred back to  **main.html**, giving the value of that text-field in form of an alert. Please help me achieve this.

```
<!-- form.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                location.href = "index.html";
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Number : <input type="text" id="no">
    <br><br>
    <a href="index.html"><input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"></a>
</body>
</html>


<!-- main.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var e;
            $("#add").bind("click", function(){
                $("#temp").load("form.html", function(data){
                    location.href="form.html";
                    e = $("#no").val();
                });
            });
            $("#disp").html(e);

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="temp" style="display:none;"></div>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
    <div id="disp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use `localStorage`?

Comment: Or cookies or in iframe or in new window or using `get ` method and read from the query string.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Is `form.html` being opened in a separate window, or being navigated to in the same window?  It's not really clear.

Comment: @David, form.html opens in a separate window

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
            var e;
            $("#add").bind("click", function(){
                $("#temp").load("form.html", function(data){ 
       $("#temp").css({'display':'block'});
       $("#add").css({'display':'none'});
                 });
            });
            $("#disp").html(e);
   $("#submit").click(function(){
                alert($('#no').val());
            });

        });
```

```html
<!-- main.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="temp" style="display:none;"></div>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
    <div id="disp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- form.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  Number :
  <input type="text" id="no">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="index.html">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `form.html` is opened in a separate window by `main.html`, then it can use [the `window.opener` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) to refer back to `main.html`.

So on `main.html` you might have something like this:

```
function setValue(value) {
    document.getElementById('someID').value = value;
}
```

Then in `form.html` you can invoke that function:

```
window.opener.setValue(document.getElementById('anotherID').value);
```

Your code may be more involved, of course.  But the general idea is that when Window A opens Window B, Window B has a direct reference to the `window` object of Window A.